# wpf Change TextBox width on mouseover

Tags: wpf, visibility

I have ListBoxItem with Textbox inside. On mouseover draggable block behind Textbox appears. Textbox autosizes to its content, that's ok, but when Drag apperas, the ListboxItem becomes wider and moves other items, it's not ok. So I need TextBox be a little wider than its content when Drag is collapsed:

```
             onMouseOver
+---------+  +----+----+
|text     |  |drag|text|
+---------+  +----+----+
```

I guess: show Drag a little, then collapse, and bind Textbox.width to some Border.ActualWidth:

```
 <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <DockPanel x:Name="drag" Width="15" >
        <DockPanel.Style>
            <Style TargetType="DockPanel">
            <!--<Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />-->
                <!--<Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBoxItem}}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>-->
            </Style>
        </DockPanel.Style>
    </DockPanel>

    <Border x:Name="bd" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />

    <TextBox x:Name="query" Grid.Column="1">
        <TextBox.Style>
            <Style TargetType="TextBox">                   
                <!--<Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBoxItem}}" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Width" Value="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=bd}" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>-->
            </Style>
        </TextBox.Style>
    </TextBox>
</Grid>
```

I make all styles in code:

```
var dispatcherTimer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
dispatcherTimer.Tick += (s1, e1) =>
{
    var mouseOverB = new Binding("IsMouseOver")
    {
        RelativeSource = new RelativeSource(RelativeSourceMode.FindAncestor, typeof(ListBoxItem), 1)
    };

    var actualB = new Binding("ActualWidth")
    {
        ElementName = "bd"
    };

    var setterVisible = new Setter(DockPanel.VisibilityProperty, Visibility.Visible);
    var setterCollapsed = new Setter(DockPanel.VisibilityProperty, Visibility.Collapsed);
    var setterWidth = new Setter(TextBox.WidthProperty, actualB);

    var panelTr = new DataTrigger()
    {
        Binding = mouseOverB,
        Value = true,
        Setters = { setterVisible }
    };

    var panelStyle = new Style(typeof(DockPanel))
    {
        Triggers = { panelTr },
        Setters = { setterCollapsed }
    };


    var txtTr = new DataTrigger()
    {
        Binding = mouseOverB,
        Value = false,
        Setters = { setterWidth }
    };

    var txtStyle = new Style(typeof(TextBox))
    {
        Triggers = { txtTr }
    };

    drag.Style = panelStyle;
    query.Style = txtStyle;
};
dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 50);
dispatcherTimer.Start();
```

That works, but I have other styles and want do it in XAML. Any suggestions?

Comment: A hint to your first question: I see that you assign the TextBox width on the Border's ActualWidth, which causes problems. If you don't want a TextBox to grow because of its inner text length, give it a fix MinWidth, and bind its Width to the ActualWidth of a visual parent Canvas.

Comment: TextBox should have size as its text content, grow and shrink.